# How to use 'onchange' in Yii2 MaskedInput widget

Tags: yii2, onchange, maskedinput

I have an Yii2 app with advanced template. There is 2 fields on my form. 1st: MaskedInput and 2nd textInput with readonly attribute.
So, I wanted to fill 2nd textInput automatically right after I have filled MaskedInput. For this I tried to use onchange. But I got following error:

> ```
> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
> Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\MaskedInput::onchange
> ```

Here is my code:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <?= Html::label("Ser num")?>
        <?= MaskedInput::widget(['name'=>'serNum',
            'mask'=>'AA 9999999',
            'onchange'=>'
                $.post("index.php?r=act/actid&serNum='.'"+$(this).val(),function(data){
                $("select#ser-sernum").html(data);
        });
            '
        ])?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'sernum')->textInput(['readonly'=>true]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <b id="actstatus"></b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-maskedinput.html#$options-detail) property:

```
<?= yii\widgets\MaskedInput::widget(['name'=>'serNum',
        'mask'=>'AA 9999999',
        'options' => [
          'onchange'=>'
              $.post("index.php?r=act/actid&serNum='.'"+$(this).val(),function(data){
              $("select#ser-sernum").html(data);
           });'
         ]
])?>
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much. I tried "clientOptions" before but didn't try "options". Now it is working, thanks again

Comment: @RasulbekAbdurasulov. `onChange` is an html property, so better to use html options.